# Retaining drop down list value in html using xslt?

Tags: html, xslt, if-statement, tibco, businessworks

Not sure if I am answering the question right, but I will try :-

I have a html page(xml+xslt) that has a drop down list containing 10 values. When I select a value, ex. ABC, I can perform add or delete or search. Now on every other pages(add, delete, search), i have a home button. When I click it, it goes to home, but the value of drop down is resetted.

How do I retain the value selected by user?

I have the following piece of code, but it is not working not sure why.

I am working on TIBCO BusinessWorks.

```
 <tr > <td>
 <select name= "GetRelationCombo">
        <xsl:for-each select="resultSet/Record">
             <xsl:sort select="REL_NAME" />

                  <option> 
                    <xsl:attribute name="value">
            <xsl:value-of select="REL_NAME" />
               </xsl:attribute>
                   <xsl:value-of select="REL_NAME" />
    <xsl:if test="REL_NAME = 'resultSet/RelationshipName'">
    <xsl:attribute name="selected">true</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>

                 </option>            
      </xsl:for-each>
 </select>
</td></tr>
```

This is the input XML:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<resultSet>
  <Record>
    <REL_NAME>ShapeID</REL_NAME>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <REL_NAME>eMPSQPType</REL_NAME>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <REL_NAME>GERSGLAccount</REL_NAME>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <REL_NAME>WageType</REL_NAME>
  </Record>
  <RelationshipName>PLANT</RelationshipName>
</resultSet>
```

Please help!! I am in middle of something big.

Comment: Thanks for providing the sample XML.  It looks like RelationshipName doesn't match any of the REL_NAME values.  Which item should be selected in this case?

Comment: sorrry for this. The XML was big enough. so i trimmed it. RelationshipName  PLANT does exist in the REL_NAME. Please consider. !

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirming.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, any attributes you use need to occur before anything inside an element, so this:

```
<xsl:if test="REL_NAME = 'resultSet/RelationshipName'">
    <xsl:attribute name="selected">true</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
```

should be above this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="REL_NAME" />
```

this isn't correct, because it will only be true when REL_NAME actually has the value "resultSet/RelationshipName":

```
REL_NAME = 'resultSet/RelationshipName'
```

This is the actual condition you need:

```
REL_NAME = ../RelationshipName
```

Modified XSL:

```
  <option>
    <xsl:attribute name="value">
      <xsl:value-of select="REL_NAME" />
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:if test="REL_NAME = ../RelationshipName">
      <xsl:attribute name="selected">true</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="REL_NAME" />
  </option>
```

As a side note, I think the correct value for the selected attribute is "selected", not "true", even though "true" might work anyway.

```
<xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
```

http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/option/selected

Comment: Thanks JLRishe, Here is the input XML :-

<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<resultSet>
 <Record>
  <REL_NAME>ShapeID</REL_NAME>
 </Record>
 <Record>
  <REL_NAME>eMPSQPType</REL_NAME>
 </Record>
 <Record>
  <REL_NAME>GERSGLAccount</REL_NAME>
 </Record>
 <Record>
  <REL_NAME>WageType</REL_NAME>
 </Record>
 <RelationshipName>PLANT</RelationshipName>
</resultSet>

Thanks

Comment: Thanks JLRishe for the help. I tried using the above, but it is not working.
when i see the drop down, it get resetted to default value. Not sure where i am getting wrong.

Comment: Did you try changing the "true" text to "selected"?  Have you verified that the XML you're passing in has the expected values?

Comment: yes. i have tried both the values, true and selected.
and the input XML is what i have paste about..

Comment: Do you have a way of verifying the output of the XSL? Is the transform done client side or server side?  If server side, is there anything in your website framework that might be changing the value of the dropdown?